# Split Function with Index Match function

Tags: google-sheets, split, index-match, split-function

I have a column that has multiple comma separated values, I need to use Split function and then run index match on that column, is it possible ? if yes somebody can help pls

Comment: I think it is possible. Share a sample workbook and show input and desired output.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this, I just tested it in google sheets.

`=INDEX(<array>,MATCH(SPLIT(<cell>,","),<array>,0))`

To be honest, I was googling for something similar and ran across this issue. My problem turned out to be that I was using `','` and NOT `","`. I suspect you asked this question for similar reasons (you tried it and it didn't work). So just to confirm, it is totally possible, the issue is likely an error with your formula.

output of a minimal example, using the above formula, matching on the first split:

[image: output of a minimal example, using the above formula]